# If $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots,a_n$ are positive real numbers with product $c$, then find the minimum value of $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_{n-1}+2a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

> If $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots,a_n$ are positive real numbers whose product is a fixed number $c$, then the minimum value of $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_{n-1}+2a_n$ is
>   (A) $n(2c)^{1/n}$
>   (B) $(n+1)c^{1/n}$
>   (C) $2nc^{1/n}$
>   (D) $(n+1)(2c)^{1/n}$

**My Approch:**
$GM=c^{1/n}$
$AM \geq GM $
For minimum value,
$\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_{n-1}+a_n}{n}=c^{1/n}$
$a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_{n-1}+a_n=nc^{1/n}$

But the question asks for $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_{n-1}+2a_n$.
The closest approximation would be to consider $a_n=GM$. But that wouldn't give you the accurate answer. How do you solve this question then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put in $b_n=2a_n$.  Then you are tp minimize $a_1+a_2+...+a_{n-1}+b_n$  given the product of those terms $a_1·a_2·...·a_{n-1}·b_n$ being equal to $2c$, and no coefficients in the terms other than $1$.  You apparently know how to solve this, and the answer follows.

Comment: Why would the product of those terms equal 2c?

Comment: What is the product with the last factor mase equal to $b_n =2a_n$, if it's $c$ with the last factor being $a_n$?

Comment: Oh right! I was thinking that c stands for the product of double of all the terms :P